# Generate Cloud Endpoint: MyApp is not configured as a web application

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a new Google App Engine application.

Within a brand new Android project, I added an App Engine project and all seems well. Now when trying to generate an endpoint for a class via **Google** > **Generate Cloud Endpoint** it has a number of *Unexpected Exception*.

Here are some of the exceptions.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project MyApp is not a web-app project

and

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: MyApp is not configured as a web application

This doesn't seem to make sense, it's an Android app but I may be mistaken with how it should act.

How do I resolve these errors with Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure someone else is bound to make the same bonehead mistake I did, so I'll answer my own question instead of deleting my shame in case it can help others.

Basically this error message happens when following https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities and you generate the endpoint class in the wrong project.

When you create a Google App Engine powered Android app, you will have at least two projects: *MyApp* and *MyApp-AppEngine*. You need to put your entity class into the *MyApp-AppEngine* project and NOT your *MyApp* project.

If you place your class within *MyApp* and generate the endpoint classes that way, you'll end up confusing Java / Eclipse / yourself / etc. It will then give you the errors

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project MyApp is not a web-app project

and

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: MyApp is not configured as a web application